# waht is the default address ip of nagios server

Tags: server, ip, nagios, nagiosxi

what is the default address IP of Nagios server?

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,<Nagios ip server>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean in nrpe.conf?

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer , yes in file nrpe.cfg

Comment: There isn't a default address, you have to configure this (or use DHCP), when setting up the server OS.

Comment: From your other question, this would be the IP address of your PC.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default address as such,

```
allowed_hosts=10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3,127.0.0.1
```

above is the configuration which is given in the nrpe.cfg file under your nagios directory which allows you to perform remote executions by allowing the connection from the host's define above, provided the port 5666 is open.